# Getting interstitial video ads despite blocking it in Admob “Ad type” setting 20 days back

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated admob interstitial ad in an andriod webview app, My code handle showing image / text interstitial ads, but when I get video interstitial ads which are shown in full screen video player my app crashes post video ad closer or skip ad. To avoid crash I unchecked video ads in ad type for this interstial ad unit.

Any help or suggestion on why video ad is shown despite blocking it would be very much helpful as this is holding my app launch.

Comment: Are you showing any videos or audio right before or after the ad? If so, it might be necessary to pause those before showing the ad. I had some crashed due to using audio and not pausing it before the ad started.

Comment: Hi Andreas Evjenth, 
Thanks for your reply and information. Yes, audio is used right before ad code. I will try to pause audio before ad in HTML. Currently developer has added the error to exception, so as of now crash do not happen but the what is puzzling me is why video ads are shown when it is blocked in admob settings.